# How Do We Know Electron Wavefunction Should Be Antisymmetric to Electron Exchange?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, fermions, bosons, pauli-exclusion-principle

As far as I know, electrons are indistinguishable particles which means that physical observables should be independent to electron exchange. Only way this can be done if the wavefunction stays the same after exchange (bosons) or flips the sign (fermions). How do we know or how did we discover that electrons go into fermionic category? I guess we know it from experiment or observation since antisymmetry gives rise to Pauli's exclusion principle, but I am not sure if this is the case.

Comment: Yes, experimental results coincide with the predictions made by quantum mechanics. From a theoretical point of view, check the so-called spin-statistics theorem. See also [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/652510/is-paulis-exclusion-principle-a-postulate-of-quantum-mechanics).

Answer (score 1):

The exclusion principle came first as a physical idea to capture phenomena of atomic spectroscopy and chemistry. Exchange antisymmetry is the way that subsequent mathematical abstraction captured this physical idea. So, the phenomena gave rise to the exclusion principle, and it gave rise to the exchange antisymmetry abstraction.